# Validation exception fails if field is empty Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I m trying to do a simple validation on textbox, its a required field and cannot be empty. Initially value will be empty so when user do not enter any value into the field and directly clicks Save button then valitaion is not triggered. It works fine when user types something and then deletes the value from it then it works perfectly and shows the validation error message. Is there anyway to do validation check after user clicks save button.

```
    [Display(Name = "Sometext", Description = "Some text")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
    public string SomeText
    {
        get
        {
            return _someText; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (_someText== value &&
                value != string.Empty)
            {
                return;
            }

            Validate(value, "someText");//This calls Validator.ValidateProperty method
            _someText= value;
            FirePropertyChanged("someText");
        }
    }
```

Please suggest!

Thanks in advance
Sai

Answer (score 1):

Josh Twist has given a work around for this. This works perfectly..

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Silverlight_Validation_and_MVVM_Part_II.aspx

Comment: true, i've moved over to his approach aswell, it has flaws no doubt, but its much better than the build-in alternative

Answer (score 1):

You could also call on your command execution

```
Validator.ValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this,null,null),true);
```

This should validate all properties on your viewmodel, assuming you call this from your viewmodel

**edit: Response to comment**

You could have a property like so (below) in your BaseViewModel (every viewmodel extends BaseViewModel), and then disallow save with a proper message

```
    protected bool HasValidationErrors
        {
            get
            {
                try { 
                      Validator.ValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this, null, null), true); 
                      return false; 
                    }
                catch (ValidationException) { return true; }

            }
        }
```

In your command you would call it like so

```
public void SaveCommandExecuted(object parameter)
    {   

        if (HasValidationErrors)
        {
            ShowValidationError();
        }
    }
```

Another thing, you could try is to bind the View event for validation errors to a listener in you viewmodel

```
    MyProgram.ViewModels.BaseViewModel baseViewModel = page.Resources["DataSource"] as MyProgram.ViewModels.BaseViewModel;

    page.BindingValidationError += new EventHandler<ValidationErrorEventArgs>(baseModel.OnValidationError);
```

then in your BaseViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<ValidationError> Errors { get; set; }


public void OnValidationError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case ValidationErrorEventAction.Added:
                    Errors.Add(e.Error);
                    break;
                case ValidationErrorEventAction.Removed:
                    Errors.Remove(e.Error);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

then modify HasValidationErrors to

```
protected bool HasValidationErrors
        {
            get
            {
                try { 
                      Validator.ValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this, null, null), true); 
                      return this.Errors.Count != 0; 
                    }
                catch (ValidationException) { return true; }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, That will Validate all the properties but it doesnot propagate the validation exception to UI. instead it will throw an exception.

Comment: Instead of catching the exception, you could use TryValidateObject()